# Fixing a php retrieval using an Arduino sketch. Was working, now broken

Tags: php, http, ssl, arduino, esp8266

As the title suggests, I have an Arduino sketch set up to reach out to my web server using SSL, intending to retrieve an output value from a php script.  It was working up until around 2am MST on Thursday, September 19th 2019, but sometime over the next eight hours, it stopped.  My hosting provider made significant updates that morning and I think there's now an incompatibility somewhere.  Below, I'm not including all of the code, just the pieces that should be relevant.  I've excluded the pieces about establishing a connection to wifi, my NTP configuration and the pieces about using the returned value in NeoPixel.  I set client.setInsecure because my cert changes pretty frequently, and so does the fingerprint.  This also worked prior to server maintenance.  The fingerprint displayed is an older one.  It's possible that some of this code is unnecessary, but I found that if I took out the lines dealing with fingerprint, the connection failed.

If I reach the URL from a browser, I get the correct number returned, but with the Arduino, I'm getting the DOCTYPE line instead.  I originally had HTTP/1.0 in my code, and it was working.  After the issue started, neither works, 1.0 or 2.0.

My hosting provider says the following:
Apache Version  2.4.39
PHP Version     7.3.8

Instead of getting a simple number back, I'm getting this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
```

Sketch:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

const char* host = "battletech-live.net";
const int httpsPort = 443;
String url = "/assets/scripts/php/checkTasks.php?action=getRows&uid=esp8266";
// SHA1 fingerprint of the certificate
char fingerprint[] PROGMEM = "44 DD B9 73 04 F8 EE 6B 0A 01 76 F2 98 34 F7 DE 43 60 11 54";

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFiClientSecure client;
    client.setInsecure();

    if (client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
        Serial.println("connected");

        String request = String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.0 \r\n" +
                "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
                "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        client.print(request);
        String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
        Serial.println(line);
    } else {
        Serial.println("connected failed");
    }
}

void loop() {
    getPendingTasks();
}

void getPendingTasks() {
    WiFiClientSecure client;
    client.setInsecure();
    client.setFingerprint(fingerprint);
    if (client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
        String request = String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.0 \r\n" +
                "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
                "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        client.print(request);
        String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
        Serial.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that String line = client.readStringUntil('\n'); is capturing the header line and discarding the value I want, but it's odd that it worked, but now doesn't.  The header information is mostly useless to me and I don't see that information when I hit the URL from a browser.

Comment: Here is the full response received by Arduino since the provider update.

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>400 Bad Request</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Bad Request</h1>
    <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
    </p>
    <p>Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache Server at host2011.hostmonster.com Port 443</address>
    </body></html>